# Broken DAG issue (Airflow 2.5.0)

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/dag.py", line 7, in <module>
    from training import training
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/training.py", line 6, in <module>
    from joblib import dump
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'joblib'
```

I have 'joblib' module installed already then why it is showing this module not found error??

Comment: how do you deploy your Airflow server? if in the local host, are you using the same environment which has `joblib` installed? if in docker, are you sure this lib is installed in the docker image? please edit your question and try to add some information about how your airflow is running, and how did you check that this lib is installed

Comment: I have deplopyed Airflow through docker images,I am using same environment, I checked by running that function which is using joblib in it, that is running fine, also I checked joblib in my virtualenv libraries folder.

Comment: can you add the docker compose file (and the Dockerfile if you are using a custom docker image) in order to reproduce the error and help you solve it?

Comment: I'm using 'FROM apache/airflow:2.5.0' in **DockerFile** and **docker-compose.yml** from Apache-airflow documentation, also I'm getting same above error(broken dags) for other libraries like **tweepy**, **yfinance** etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Below answer's discussion can be seen on (https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/28661)

You should build your own image and extend it by adding the packages you need https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#adding-new-pypi-packages-individually

Using _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS is highly discouraged for anything but the quick iteration while debugging your installation (see the note for details).

You don't even have to do much. Docker compose fully supports automatic building image with new dependencies and using it. See this comment in the dockerfile:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/docs/apache-airflow/howto/docker-compose/docker-compose.yaml#L46

1. In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
2. Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml and uncomment the "build" line below,
3. Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
   `image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:|version|}`
   `build: .`

You can also run **docker compose up --build** as a shortcut if you do not want to run **docker compose build** separately.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared the content of docker-compose.yml file, so I'am considering the Airflow v2.5.0 mentioned in question.

So here is the quick update from Airflow v2.1.1 and latest version, where you can specify the python lib(s) while configuring docker-compose.yml file.

```
_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- joblib==1.2.0 lxml==4.6.3 charset-normalizer==1.4.1}
```

You can find the more information related to above snippet below:

[docker-compose.yml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml)

[Environment variables supported by Docker Compose](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/docker-compose/index.html) - Check bottom section.

And don't forget to restart the docker after this changes.

`docker-compose restart`

if changes do not reflect by above command then use below command:-

`docker-compose up`

This will install all the required python lib(S) along with Airflow services.

Comment: above answer solved my problem but **docker-compose restart** doesn't work for me instead **docker-compose up** worked....thanks Nikhil Sawant

Comment: what if, I have a list of those libraries which needs to be added to PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENT, how can I add those list by putting in a single requirement.txt file? because it would be messy if I put all those libraries over there one by one.

Comment: Oh, well there is complete documentation on what you are trying to accomplish, you can build your own custom docker image in that case with all required python lib(s) which you want. Please refer to this document. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#adding-packages-from-requirements-txt

Comment: And one more thing which I want to mention here if you are using '_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:' configuration on production then please don't forget to read this thread https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/24794#issuecomment-1172978715

Comment: One gentleman also posted an answer on Github discussion which seems more perfect after reading the documentation. (https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/28661)